# Where does Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc.exe) cache OCSP-responses?

Tags: remote-desktop

Where does RDP/MSTSC cache OCSP responses on Windows 10?

I'm testing an OCSP responder implementation with remote desktop on a Windows 10 system (foo), connecting to another Windows 10 system (bar). The OCSP responder works, i.e., the remote desktop client on foo:

1. Validates bar's certificate
2. Gets the OCSP URI from that certificate
3. Receives a signed response from its query to the OCSP responder
4. Connects to bar without any certificate warnings

Now I want to clear the revocation cache to continue my testing, but I can't figure out how to do so. I've tried various `certutil` commands and rebooting foo without any luck, e.g.:

```
certutil -setreg chain\ChainCacheResyncFiletime @now
certutil -urlcache ocsp delete
```

Reference: [Delete local CRL cache in Windows | Microsoft Security Solutions](https://mssec.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/delete-local-crl-cache-in-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any definitive documentation from Microsoft on the matter, but as far as I can tell from my testing, the RDP *client* doesn't request/cache OCSP responses at all.

Rather, the RDP *server* will:

1. Query its certificate's status from the OCSP responder;
2. Cache the response, which seems to be tied to the remote desktop service state; and
3. Present the certificate's status to the client during the TLS handshake, i.e., OCSP stapling.

To clear the cached/stapled OCSP response on the RDP server, restart the *Remote Desktop Services* service (`TermService`).

---

You can test this yourself by performing a packet capture during the RDP session setup; the TLS `Server Hello` handshake should include a `Certificate Status` component.

Oddly enough, testing RDP with `openssl s_client -status -connect ...` *doesn't* show the OCSP response where testing a web server *does*. I think this is what threw me off initially. For example, testing digicert.com with OpenSSL shows the stapled OCSP response.

```
openssl s_client -status -connect digicert.com:443
```